# What is the single best resource for learning the visual studio tools?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to learn some of the basic and advanced features of visual studio, Anyone find sites that have this type of information ?

I see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86355/best-way-to-learn-visual-studio-power-features

But it seems more related to tips and advanced features.

All three versions ( 2003, 2005, 2008 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has quite a few videos demonstrating various techniques in Visual Studio:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/bb964532.aspx

Personally I'm not a fan of training videos as I find I get impatient with them (too linear, too slow, no interaction), but maybe they'll work well for others.

Answer (score 1):

STACKOVERFLOW!!!!

(Sorry, I really couldn't help myself).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version.  However I've read [Professional Visual Studio 2005](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764598465) and while I found it a little introductory for my needs, it would probably be useful for someone newer to Visual Studio though.

I notice the [2008 edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470229888) is out now too.

Comment: All three versions ( 2003, 2005, 2008 ). we have over 500 projects that we maintain :(